# RTNETLINK answers: File exists - cant restart network on my centos in aws

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, centos7

I did some changes in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file. In detail I modified the dns server.
After that change I wanted to restart network with systemctl restart network. But I receive the error

> RTNETLINK answers: File exists

My ip is managed with dhcp because I need it for restoring the machine.
We are not using NetworkManager but why is dhclient still running? What do I have to change that "systemctl restart network" will work again?